# jQuery: Hidden msg shows every time I get or refresh web page

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-tabs

I made msg which appears when "Save" button on web page is pressed and disappears after few sec, but there are two problems. First one is that when I click link to that page, I get msg right after web page appears. Here is the code:

```
    $(".success").fadeIn(1500).delay(2500).fadeOut(2000);
```

And here is some added code, which have problem with very short time of showing msg. Msg disappears in millisecond.

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
    $(".success").fadeIn(1500).delay(2500).fadeOut(2000);});
```

My friend told me that it might be cause of refreshing whole page, after clicking "Save" button.

Second problem is that if I click "Save" button on some other tab (I'm using jQuery tabs) it will send me back to the first tab. How could I stay on current tab after this action?

Comment: It looks like you have combined 2 (or 3?) problems into one question, which makes this fairly confusing question to answer. Consider only asking one question at a time and removing anything irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, this is my first question, so I hope that I'll improve myself. Also, I'm not sure why do you hurry to give me negative mark, only cause you don't like or don't understand my questions. Anyway thx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

button is a link ? Maybe you just have to stop event propageation, [have a look at this](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Basically just to

```
$("#button").click(function(evt){
$(".success").fadeIn(1500).delay(2500).fadeOut(2000);
evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Button is not link:

    <div class="button">
                <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="next" value="Save" action="saveAssessControlSettings" /></span><div>

This solution doesn't work. Maybe, cause I'm beginner in this.

Comment: Have a look to jQuery selectors, my code $('#button') matches only element with id='button' if you want to select your <div class='button'> use $('div.button')

Answer (score 0):

If you call this within $(document).ready or similar events functions,
it will be executed immediately on all elements having class "success".

> $(".success").fadeIn(1500).delay(2500).fadeOut(2000);

Since you did not post enough of your javascript implementation here,
it is impossible to know for sure what the issue is. Neither do we know
anything about the elements these lines act upon.